# How can I transfer output that appears on the console and format it so that it appears on a web page?

Tags: java, html, wicket

```
package collabsoft.backlog_reports.c4;



import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

//import collabsoft.backlog_reports.c4.Report;

public class Report {

private Connection con;

 public Report(){
  connectUsingJDBC();
 }
 public static void main(String args[]){
  Report dc = new Report();
  dc.reviewMeeting(6, 8, 10);
dc.createReport("dede",100);
//dc.viewReport(100);
// dc.custRent(3344,123,22,11-11-2009);
 }

 /**
  the following method is used to connect to the database
 **/


 public  void connectUsingJDBC() {
  // This is the name of the ODBC data source 
  String dataSourceName = "Simple_DB";
  try {
   // loading the driver in the memory
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   // This is the connection URL
   String dbURL = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName; 
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Collabsoft","root","");
   // This line is used to print the name of the driver and it would throw an exception if a problem occured
   System.out.println("User connected using driver: " + con.getMetaData().getDriverName());

   //Addcustomer(con,1111,"aaa","aaa","aa","aam","111","2222","111");
   //rentedMovies(con);
   //executePreparedStatement(con);
   //executeCallableStatement(con);
   //executeBatch(con);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 /** 
  *this code is to link the SQL code with the java for the task
  *as an admin I should be able to create a report of a review meeting including notes, tasks and users
  *i will take the task id and user id and note id that will be needed to be added in the review
  *meeting report and i will display the information related to these ida
  **/




   public  void reviewMeeting(int taskID, int userID, int noteID)// law el proc bt return table
 {
  try{
   CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{CALL report_review_meeting(?,?,?)}");

         callableStatement.setInt(1,taskID);
                        callableStatement.setInt(2,userID);
                        callableStatement.setInt(3,noteID);

   ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery(); // or executeupdate() or updateQuery
   ResultSetMetaData rsm = resultSet.getMetaData();  
   int numOfColumns = rsm.getColumnCount();
   System.out.println("lojayna");

   while (resultSet.next()) 
   {
    System.out.println("New Row:");
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfColumns; i++)
     System.out.print(rsm.getColumnName(i) + ": " + resultSet.getObject(i) + " ");
    System.out.println();
   }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  { 
   System.out.println("E");
  }  
 } 



   //////////////////////////////////
   /////////////////////////////////



   public  void allproject(int projID)// law el proc bt return table
   {
    try{
     CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{CALL all_project(?)}");

           callableStatement.setInt(1,projID);
                          //callableStatement.setInt(2,userID);
                          //callableStatement.setInt(3,noteID);

     ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery(); // or executeupdate() or updateQuery
     ResultSetMetaData rsm = resultSet.getMetaData();  
     int numOfColumns = rsm.getColumnCount();
     System.out.println("lojayna");

     while (resultSet.next()) 
     {
      System.out.println("New Row:");
      for (int i = 1; i <= numOfColumns; i++)
       System.out.print(rsm.getColumnName(i) + ": " + resultSet.getObject(i) + " ");
      System.out.println();
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
     System.out.println("E");
    }  
   } 














   ///////////////////////////////












   /**
    * here i take the event id and i take a string report and then
    *  i relate the report with the event

    **/




     public  void createReport(String report,int E_ID )// law el proc bt return table
   {
    try{





     Statement st = con.createStatement();

  st.executeUpdate("UPDATE e_vent SET e_vent.report=report WHERE e_vent.E_ID= E_ID;");

    /* CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{CALL Create_report(?,?)}");

           callableStatement.setString(1,report);
                          callableStatement.setInt(2,E_ID);


     ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery(); // or executeupdate() or updateQuery
     ResultSetMetaData rsm = resultSet.getMetaData();  
     int numOfColumns = rsm.getColumnCount();
     System.out.println("lojayna");

     while (resultSet.next()) 
     {
      System.out.println("New Row:");
      for (int i = 1; i <= numOfColumns; i++)
       System.out.print(rsm.getColumnName(i) + ": " + resultSet.getObject(i) + " ");
      System.out.println();
     }*/
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
     System.out.println("E");
     System.out.println(e);
    }  
   }




 /** 
  *in the following method i view the report of the event having the ID  eventID 
  **/





   public  void viewReport(int eventID)// law el proc bt return table
 {
  try{
   CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{CALL view_report(?)}");

         callableStatement.setInt(1,eventID);



   ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery(); // or executeupdate() or updateQuery
   ResultSetMetaData rsm = resultSet.getMetaData();  
   int numOfColumns = rsm.getColumnCount();
   System.out.println("lojayna");

   while (resultSet.next()) 
   {
    System.out.println("New Row:");
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfColumns; i++)
     System.out.print(rsm.getColumnName(i) + ": " + resultSet.getObject(i) + " ");
    System.out.println();
   }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  { 
   System.out.println("E");
  }  
 } 





















}
```

// the result of these methods is being showed on the console , i am using WIcket and i want it 2 be showed on the web  how is that done ?!

Comment: And make your question much shorter and more succinct, if you want it to be read.

Comment: Please read this http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and http://sscce.org and please pay attention to message formatting. Check the FAQ for details and make use of message preview (at the bottom of message editor) to verify if anything is right. Right now it very much look like an disinterested copy'n'paste action without any efforts from your side on. And fact on forums and QA sites is, you get as many effort back as you put in yourself...

Comment: What do you mean by transferring output? Do you want to write a static html page or do you actually want the text to display directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do is simply dump text to an html page, use a StringBuilder and/or create an extra class with methods to ouput text with html tags.

If you actually want to animate a web site, the most "simple" way would be to use Servlets. See the link below for a tutorial.

http://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/tutorials/introduction-to-java-servlets-with-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple solution go with James' answer. However if you need to asynchronously transfer data between applications or even platforms (double-time when they are not local), you may want to look into [JMS api](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) (when you are using Glassfish as application server it's quite easy or Apache ActiveMQ implementation does good job). I'm using it in deployment where system programs/scripts are called from webapp and then these programs report back to webapp via JMS when they finish.

Alternatively you can dump that output to database as well.